# Scaling returns to use PCA?

Tags: covariance, pca, markowitz

Many machine learning techniques perform better, if the data is preprocessed - either by normalization (MaxMin Scaler) or standardization (Standard Scaler). But that comes with a lack of interpretability and some other problems.

My question concerning this: If I want apply PCA for the covariance matrix of the returns, is scaling the data a thing I want to do or rather not?

Thanks!